# How do I remind someone of my birthday?

Tags: technology

How do you remind someone its your birthday with out telling them? Today is my birthday and I know we all forget birthdays so how do I remind them indirectly?

Comment: Tell them about your big plans for your birthday and ask them if they want to come along.

Comment: You just remember he's or she's birthday first. He/she would remember yours. If he/she wouldn't, you keep remembering his/her birthday every year. One day you'll reach your goal. I hope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set your birth date in a social media, because they usually remind people about others' birthday.

Another way, if you're talking to the person, you could mention you are doing something just because it is your birthday, for example:

*"I took the day for relaxing today. At least on my birthday I think I deserve it."*

You get the point, right? Try tweaking it, so it doesn't sound *'needy'*, if that's not what you want.

Also, if you're planning to throw a party, you could always invite people you would like to remember your birthday.

Comment: Along these same lines, you could say, "I can't believe I'm going to be 25 years old on Saturday!" The focus of that statement _seems_ to be that you can't believe you're that age. But it also provides the information that Saturday is your birthday.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say where you want the remembering to happen. Is is at work? Take cake and write a sign.

At sport or in the pub? Buy a round of drinks.

On social media? Do you care? Well, as Leonardo suggested, enter your birthday in your favourite tool and it will do the job for you.

But remember, if you expect people to remember and mark your birthday, you have to do the same for them.

Answer (score 3):

Invite them to your birthday party of course!

Answer (score 1):

In my birthday month  I start a birthday countdown. I write on a sign and/or post somewhere. "Only ____ more shopping days until my birthday. Shop early and avoid the last minute rush"  I try to do it every year at the same time. Usually, the beginning of my birthday month.

It's really funny because over the years my friends and family are used to me doing it. If I don't post it or write it on a sign in the house,  they start asking... "So how many more shopping days do we have?"